# 2D Cutout Animation workflo in Blender 2.8

Tags: animation

I'm trying to adapt cutout animaton workflow that I learned using Toon Boom software into blender. Most of it can be easily done, but I can't figure out how to handle substitution drawings. For example - it's a set of different hand drawings, that share same pivot point and can be switched on timeline. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0E4akLWpGM - Here's how it works in Toon Boom.

I've seen that someone handled it with drivers, but maybe there is better way to solve it?

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaThn5iWt_o) or maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MH__FRPGIdk)

Comment: See Time Offset Modifier, mode Fixed Frame. Att
Cristiano